# Getter returning undefined in JS even though it works in the first call

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a getter that works the first time when I use it in pug, but then it returns undefined later in my code (even though the code is exactly the same). What's going wrong?

Question object class and getter:

```
class Question {
  constructor(op, min, max) {
    this.op = op;
    this.num1 = ranNums(min, max);
    this.num2 = ranNums(min, max);
  }

  get operation() {
    if (this.op === 'Addition') {
      this.op = '+'
      this.answer = this.num1 + this.num2;
      return this.op;
    } else if (this.op === 'Subtraction') {
      this.op = '-'
      this.answer = this.num1 - this.num2;
      return this.op;
    } else if (this.op === 'Multiplication') {
      this.op = "*"
      this.answer = this.num1 * this.num2;
      return this.op;
    } else {
      this.op = '÷';
      this.answer = this.num1 / this.num2;
      return this.op;
    }
  }
```

code in pug: (The getter is first used in the paragraph, which does what I wanted. However, the code after the script tags don't).

```
html
 head
  p#question #{questions[score].num1} #{questions[score].operation}  #{questions[score].num2} 

//after script tag
if (input === questions[score].answer) {
     score++
     scoreElem.innerHTML = score;
     qElem.innerHTML = `${questions[score].num1} ${questions[score].operation}  ${questions[score].num2}`


}
```

This is how I created the question array (in another function):

```
function createQuestions(op = 'Addition', min = 0, max = 20, amnt = 20) {
  const questionArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < amnt; i++) {
    questionArray.push(new Question(op, min, max));
  }

  return questionArray;
}
```

Then this is what appears if I console.log `questions` and `questions[score]`:

```
[questions] =
0: {op: "+", num1: 6, num2: 1, answer: 7}
1: {op: "Addition", num1: 6, num2: 2}
2: {op: "Addition", num1: 0, num2: 8}

questions[score] = {op: "+", num1: 6, num2: 1, answer: 7}
answer: 7
num1: 6
num2: 1
op: "+"

//it has a + and answer property which the others don't have.
```

So when you first enter the page, you get something like 10 + 40. If you get the question correct, it gives you the next pair of numbers, but the "+" becomes undefined.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what `questions` is?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put that in. `questions` is just an array filled with the Question object. The first item in the array gets an `answer` and correct `op` property but the rest of the Questions don't.

Comment: Try to add a `console.log` before the `if` which prints `questions` and `questions[score]`.

Comment: Ok. Could you share how you create this array? The contents of it.

Comment: Ok @MaazSyedAdeeb . I edited my post to show how I created the array and what questions/questions[score] was.

Comment: You are mixing `#{pugRenderedVariables}` and `${locallyRenderedVariables}`. How did you get the browser not to spit errors on incrementing `score` and accessing `questions`? Because if you force-serialized `questions` like `var clientSideJSVariable = #{JSON.stringify(questions)};`, your getter surely won't survive this... on a side note, the whole process of transforming `op` and setting `answer` should be done at `constructor` time IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by making a setter instead and using it in my for loop when I created the question array. Thank you guys for your ideas!